# ZSH Symfony Console Auto Completion

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, zsh-completion

I'm trying to create a ZSH auto completion script for Symfony's Console, I almost finished it but I block in the last part. I need to create an array thanks to a function returns, but I don't know how to process.
Here's the code I wrote:

```
_find_console () {
    echo "php $(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1 -name 'console' -type f | head -n 1)"
}

_console_get_command_list () {
    `_find_console` --no-ansi | \
        sed "1,/Available commands/d" | \
        awk '/ [a-z]+/ { print $0 }' | \
        sed -E 's/^[ ]+//g' | \
        sed -E 's/[:]+/\\:/g' | \
        sed -E 's/[ ]{2,}/\:/g'
}

_console () {
    local -a commands
    commands=(`_console_get_command_list`)
    _describe 'commands' commands
}

compdef _console php console
compdef _console console
```

If I execute the command line, it formats it in the proper way. But used with ZSH the output is like this:

```
acme:hello         -- Hello
assets:install     -- Installs
cache:warmup       -- Warms
```

and the formatted function returns:

```
acme\:hello:Hello World example command
assetic\:dump:Dumps all assets to the filesystem
cache\:warmup:Warms up an empty cache
```

The words that are not displayed, are used as a command completion. Here's an example: [Asciinema example](https://asciinema.org/a/06x3dyl2mtkj4hopm64eg5ujv).

If I take the returns and use it directly into the array, it works well.

Comment: I can't help with your array problem, but you should be aware that you can condense all of your piped data cleanup, (sed,awk,sed,sed,...) into one call to awk. Read about the `sub()` function, it's a little different than `sed` but the regexps should be about the same. Good luck.

Comment: What's the issue here exactly? I didn't follow the various outputs and what's going on here exactly.